# How do I send a list of items through a futures::Sink?

Tags: rust, future

I have a list of items to send through a futures::`Sink`:

```
let mut list = VecDeque::new();
/* add a bunch of Packet items to list */
let (sink, stream) = tcp_stream.framed(PacketCodec).split();
```

I can send one packet using

```
if let Some(first) = list.pop_front() {
    sink.send(first);
}
```

How do I send the whole list?

Comment: *"The following clearly doesn't work*" - how so? Can you include the error, or describe what behavior you're seeing?

Comment: Please produce a [MCVE] when asking questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I bet that the **missing error message** says something about *expected a `T`, found a `&T`*. If that's the case, I'd strongly recommend that you go back and re-read through [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/), as this would not be a problem regarding Tokio, but rather basic Rust ownership.

Comment: sorry, i added code that doesn't work to express conceptually what i wanted, but it doesn't work for many reasons including ownership and lifetime problems. i see that it is a distraction rather than conceptually illustrative, so i'll delete it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When using a new piece of software, I find it very useful to read the documentation before diving in too deep. The Rust community has, in general, provided pretty great resources.

For example, the Tokio project has an [entire site of documentation](https://tokio.rs/docs/getting-started/hello-world/) which includes a [selection of working examples](https://tokio.rs/docs/getting-started/echo/). The [generated API documentation for `Sink`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.4/futures/sink/trait.Sink.html) is also invaluable here.

Another thing that I recommend all programmers learn to do is to create a [MCVE](/help/mcve) of the problem. This allows them to focus on the core of the problem while also removing cruft and honing the words behind the problem. Here's one for this case:

```
use futures::{Sink, SinkExt}; // 0.3.4

fn thing(mut sink: impl Sink<i32>) {
    let mut all_the_things = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    while let Some(v) = all_the_things.pop() {
        sink.send(v);
    }
}
```

We get the error message

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `impl Sink<i32>: std::marker::Unpin` is not satisfied
 --> src/lib.rs:7:14
  |
3 | fn thing(mut sink: impl Sink<i32>) {
  |                    -------------- help: consider further restricting this bound: `impl Sink<i32> + std::marker::Unpin`
...
7 |         sink.send(v);
  |              ^^^^ the trait `std::marker::Unpin` is not implemented for `impl Sink<i32>`
```

Let's turn back to the API documentation for [`SinkExt::send`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.4/futures/sink/trait.SinkExt.html#method.send)...

```
fn send(&mut self, item: Item) -> Send<Self, Item>
where
    Self: Unpin,
```

From this, we can see that `send` requires that the type implement `Unpin`, so let's change that:

```
use futures::{Sink, SinkExt}; // 0.3.4
use std::marker::Unpin;

fn thing(mut sink: impl Sink<i32> + Unpin) {
    let mut all_the_things = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    while let Some(v) = all_the_things.pop() {
        sink.send(v);
    }
}
```

This compiles, but has a warning:

```
warning: unused `futures_util::sink::send::Send` that must be used
 --> src/lib.rs:8:9
  |
8 |         sink.send(v);
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(unused_must_use)]` on by default
  = note: futures do nothing unless you `.await` or poll them
```

Reviewing the API again, we see it returns a [`Send`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.4/futures/sink/struct.Send.html) value. That's strange, isn't it? It's actually not *that* strange, once you see that `Send` implements `Future` - pushing something into the stream might block if the stream is full; this is the concept of *back pressure*. Having the result be a `Future` is how you can know when the item has actually been added to the stream.

One solution is to drive that future to completion with `.await` and making out function `async`:

```
use futures::{Sink, SinkExt}; // 0.3.4
use std::marker::Unpin;

async fn thing(mut sink: impl Sink<i32> + Unpin) {
    let mut all_the_things = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    while let Some(v) = all_the_things.pop() {
        sink.send(v)
            .await
            .unwrap_or_else(|_| panic!("Unable to send item"));
    }
}
```

This compiles, but isn't super pretty. Turning back to the documentation, we can also see [`Sink::send_all`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.4/futures/sink/trait.SinkExt.html#method.send_all), which takes a [`TryStream`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.4/futures/stream/trait.TryStream.html). We can create a `Stream` from an iterator by using [`stream::iter`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.4/futures/stream/fn.iter.html) and driving the future returned by `send_all` to completion:

```
use futures::{stream, Sink, SinkExt}; // 0.3.4
use std::marker::Unpin;

async fn thing(mut sink: impl Sink<i32> + Unpin) {
    let all_the_things = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let mut stream = stream::iter(all_the_things.into_iter().map(Ok));

    sink.send_all(&mut stream)
        .await
        .unwrap_or_else(|_| panic!("Unable to send item"));
}
```

Comment: great answer! https://tokio.rs is also a fantastic pointer. it definitely needs to be upranked in google. i've been using the sources and docs and a couple of blogs to figure out tokio.

Comment: I'm sure that the Google rankings will steadily climb; Tokio 0.1 was only released 2 weeks ago after all!

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. It made something click for me, about why you would intentionally design an API to take advantage of Rust's move semantics.

Comment: @PeterHall great! I'm not 100% sure, but I think that in this case, the move semantics also help with the "zero-additional-cost" aspect of futures.